# C# generic type error when adding to a Collection

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to do the following in C# and don't understand why this is not allowed.

```
namespace Test;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      List<Base<IModelData>> list = new();
      list.Add(new Customer());
    }
}

interface IModel { }

interface IModelData { }
    

abstract class Base<T> : IModelData {
    
}

abstract class BaseData: IModelData {
    
}

class CustomerData : BaseData {
}

class Customer: Base<CustomerData> {
    
}
```

This gives a compilation error (on the list.Add method):

`Compilation error (line 11, col 13): Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Test.Customer' to 'Test.Base<Test.IModelData>'`

Customer does inherit Base, and it's generic type argument does inherit IModelData so why is this not possible?

How can this be done then, to actually be able to add any subclass (similar to Customer) to a collection like List above?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: This isn't really about collections - `Customer` simply isn't a `Base<IModelData>`, it's a `Base<CustomerData>`. You can see that without any collections: `Base<IModelData> x = new Customer();` will fail to compile too.

Comment: Just because `A` is-a `B`, that does not automatically mean `G<A>` is-a `G<B>`.

Comment: Thank you both, not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand generic type in Java's way:

1. You can remove all the generic types with angle brackets
2. replace them with `Object` in parameters and return values
3. apply appropriate cast operations

and the code should work just fine.

That's why in Java, generic type inside generic type should be omitted like this

```
List<Base<>> list = new XxxList<>();
```